# Using Multidimensional Array to file JSON data to SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, json, multidimensional-array

I'm writing a script which uses CURL to fetch JSON data from an API. I've reached a slightly confusing point when looking at how to store the data from JSON to the database itself.

The table shows the JSON key and the corresponding SQL column header.

```
----------------------------
| JSON    | MySQL          |
----------------------------
| name    | name           |
| street  | address_line_1 |
| city    | city           |
| country | country        |
| zip     | postcode       |
| id      | api_id         |
----------------------------
```

There's several different JSON trees of data returned where the key name is completely unrelated to the names in the database, so overall having the SQL headings match the keys isn't possible.

Assume that I have already fetched and ran JSON_DECODE on the returned JSON.

```
$json[0] = (
    ['name'] => 'Venue Name',
    ['street'] => 'Street Name',
    ['city'] => 'City',
    ['country'] => 'United Kingdom',
    ['zip'] => 'NE123ER',
    ['id'] => 'API Identifier'
);
```

And that I have already successfully used the following code to output all items (some of the data returned is nested, such as in this case).

```
foreach($json as $event)
{
    $iter = new RecursiveArrayIterator($event);
    foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($iter) as $key => $value) {
        if($iter->hasChildren())
        {
            if($key === 'id'){

            } elseif($key === 'name'){

            } elseif($key === 'street'){

            } elseif($key === 'city'){

            } elseif($key === 'country'){

            } elseif($key === 'zip'){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know I will essentially need to end up with a resulting array of data which I'll then be able to write to the MySQL database.

```
$mysql_write[0] = (
    ['name'] => 'Venue Name',
    ['address_line'] => 'Street Name',
    ['city'] => 'City',
    ['country'] => 'United Kingdom',
    ['postcode'] => 'NE123ER',
    ['api_id'] => 'API Identifier'
);
```

But I can't figure out how to change the keys. One idea was to make a conversion tree type thing where they key would be the current target and the value would be used when writing to the new array for SQL writing.

```
$venue_tree = array(
    array('name' => 'name'),
    array('street' => 'address_line_1'),
    array('city' => 'city'),
    array('country' => 'country'),
    array('zip' => 'postcode'),
    array('id' => 'facebook_id')
);
```

But at this point I've confused myself. Does this make sense to anyone?

Comment: In short can you mention your input and expected output?

Comment: Just made a quick edit. The $json array is the input, and the $mysql_write is the expected output. Sorry about that.

Comment: `$mysql_write[0]` and `$json[0]` are looking same i think?

Comment: What is your current SQL Statement?

Comment: $json's associative keys are from the information which comes back from the API. $mysql_write's associative keys match the table's headers where the data will need to be written to. I essentially need to swap the two around.

Comment: The SQL statement hasn't been done yet - I basically need to prepare a multidimensional array of data to loop through for insertion.

Comment: @AmazinglyVacant I hope you are expecting this which i have just posted

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting this, Mapping keys to other keys.

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/785682)

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$json = array(
    'name' => 'Venue Name',
    'street' => 'Street Name',
    'city' => 'City',
    'country' => 'United Kingdom',
    'zip' => 'NE123ER',
    'id' => 'API Identifier'
);
$venue_tree = array(
    'name' => 'name',
    'street' => 'address_line_1',
    'city' => 'city',
    'country' => 'country',
    'zip' => 'postcode',
    'id' => 'facebook_id');
$result=array();
foreach($venue_tree as $key => $changedKey)
{
    $result[$changedKey]=$json[$key];
}
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [name] => Venue Name
    [address_line_1] => Street Name
    [city] => City
    [country] => United Kingdom
    [postcode] => NE123ER
    [facebook_id] => API Identifier
)
```